Italian traveling Rome - Kuwait - Manila, 6 hour layover, visa needed?
I have a layover in Kuwait for almost 6 hour with conneticting flight to Manila with Italian passport from Rome to Manila, do I need a visa for it?
I travel with Kuwait airline for both legs.

Probably not.  There are many Kuwait transfer questions already on this site.  Have you looked through them?

Im trying to search but like confusing...thank for your reply
